# how to create a postgresql database that can storage data from a exceed 10000 columns csv table?

Tags: python, postgresql, pgadmin, sharding

I'm an SQL novice, I have a big data table with attributes exceeding 10000 columns which is hosted by CSV, and those columns come from multiple sites, I tried to import them into a database to manage them due to most of them are insignificant but sometimes I still need them and update or add new data onwards.

Now the problem is the database table columns limit can't hold so many fields. I tried to find a way to separately storage those data in several tables of a database and use a single interface to select all of the associated data.
like
table1 with two columns,  column1, column2,
and table2 with two columns, column3,column4,
those two tables connect through column1 and column3, I want to select column1 and get column2,4 data together.

[csv data](https://gofile.io/d/7Jdewz)

Comment: 1) Per here [Postgres limits](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/limits.html): *columns per table  1,600* and this is upper limit so depending on type it could be less.  So you can't import a 10000 column wide CSV file. 2) I have no idea what *...database table can’t support the column exceeding 255 or less, ...* means? Add as text a more detailed explanation to your question.

Comment: Think about a smarter data structure than 10k fields.

Comment: Hi @AdrianKlaver thank you for your reply, Regarding 2), I mean the columns per table limit is 255, but now I know I made a mistake.

Comment: Hi @KlausD. Thanks for your suggestion, should I separate the data into several parts then build a database in advance that contains associated tables, and use the SQL to import the data to each table separately? Hope I made my thoughts clear.

Comment: Something like that, but of cause you know the fields and you have to find the patterns in the fields to create the structure.

Comment: Create multiple tables (100 or so), all with the same value for the primary key and each table an additional 100 columns for your content. Then spread the content of your CSV over these 100 tables. However, I would try to create a CSV with slightly less columns, 10000 columns is imho unworkable.

Comment: @user23018244 why are there 10K columns? *It mattes a lot*. It's one thing to have 10K optional columns, quite another to use columns as rows, to store a series of measurements. You can store optional columns in a JSON column. If you have a wide-format file though, the real solution is to convert the data to long format before importing it. You can't query or aggregate along columns

Answer (score 0):

Create a table with the important and frequent columns as normal columns and add a `jsonb` column. Convert all the rare and unimportant columns into a JSON and store it in the `jsonb` column. If you need to search for attributes of that JSON, create a GIN index on the column.

Comment: That would be a good solution if the columns are optional. That's how SQL Server implements sparse columns. It won't work as well (or as easily) if the file is actually a wide-format data set, using columns to store measurements. The data would have to be converted to long format and stored either in a proper table or as a JSON array.

Comment: This seems like a good solution to me, most of the time I only use a few fields. but I'm not familiar with the jsonb format. I'll try to study how to use this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a few limitations to Postgres. If you are using this to do indexing at scale, you might consider something like pg_bm25, or otherwise you might want to instead use column-oriented Postgres if your data has much fewer rows than columns in its current format?